# generate seo friendly url for multi language system using php .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have this url's for multi language system using php :

```
http://mydomain/ <-- default language english (en)
http://mydomain/index.php?lang=de
http://mydomain/index.php?lang=fr
http://mydomain/index.php?lang=tr
```

Now, for another page i have this url:

```
http://mydomain/article.php?id=xx <-- show article details
http://mydomain/article.php?list=all  <-- show article archive
http://mydomain/gallery.php?id=xx
http://mydomain/faq.php?id=xx
http://mydomain/faq.php?list=all
http://mydomain/contact.php
```

Now, i need to create seo friendly url using php and htaccess Like This :

for index:

```
http://mydomain/  <-- for default
http://mydomain/de/
http://mydomain/fr/
```

for article ie:(`domain/lang/id/title.html`)

```
http://mydomain/de/articles/22/test.html
```

for page:

```
http://mydomain/de/contact.html
```

for archive:

```
http://mydomain/de/articles/listall.html
```

in htaccess i write this code for article :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^articles/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?.html$ articles.php?id=$1
```

but this worked for one language not multiple language. how do can i create seo friendly url for multi language system?!

Answer (score 0):

I've solve this issue using this way

```
<?
$request_uri=explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);;

$lang_code=$request_uri[1];
$page_code=$request_uri[2];
?>
```

For **de/articles/listall.html** you will get **$lang_code=de** and page code: **$page_code=articles**

and then you can include content from the exact lang file:

```
include('.$page_code.'/content_'.$lang_code.'.php');
```

Real path for content are:

```
articles/content_de.php
articles/content_en.php
```